How do PCB trace width calculators find the coefficients from the IPC-2221?
PCB trace width calculators like this one and many others like it always quote at the bottom something like this,

For IPC-2221 internal layers: k = 0.024, b = 0.44, c = 0.725
For IPC-2221 external layers: k = 0.048, b = 0.44, c = 0.725
where k, b, and c are constants resulting from curve fitting to the
IPC-2221 curves

looking at the IPC-2221 document here (page 50 on the PDF, 38 of the document) are the curves that they mention. But I can't find how they figured out those values for k, b, and c. It mentions curve fitting so I'm guessing they just followed the lines and extrapolated to different values? Are we sure these are correct?

Test it yourself. Put some values into the equation and see if they match the published curve.

Article on curve fitting: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve_fitting If you have specific questions regarding curve fitting, you might try the Mathematics site.

@Mattman944 It's not that I don't understand the concept, it's that we just accepted these values for some reason without anyone anywhere confirming. They're not even written in the actrual paper.

When the results are for something important, like a product design, I don't always trust online calculators either. I double check using an official source.

@Mattman944 So it would be best to always use the curves instead?
